# How can I make multiple smaller images resize by the same amount as a big image under them

Tags: html, css

I have one big image (let's say it's a map) and multiple smaller images (points on the map) that are shown on this image on hover event. Currently I'm positioning smaller images with `position: absolute` but when I got to the point where the screen width forces my big image to resize, smaller images are not placed where I want them to be. How can I make this work using CSS and not making this images too big so the user can hover only on the exact image I want them to hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. get the image sizes
2. two set listener for resize
3. when resize is triggered get ratio
4. use the ratio to resize the
5. smaller images

```
    var startWidth = 0;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
         var el = document.getElementById("the-img");
         startWidth = el.offsetWidth;
         // use offSetWidth & offSetHeight to get the dimension of your smaller image(s) 
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', getRatio);

    function getRatio(){
         var el = document.getElementById("the-img");
         ratio = startWidth/el.offsetWidth;

         var smallerImgWid = ratio * orginialSmallImgWid;
         var smallerImgHeigh = ratio * origonalSmallImgHeight;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Works great :)